# Finding the highest sum of two columns in a data set

Tags: r

I have the following 3 column data set in R:

```
 Year  Boys  Girls
 2018  5000  4000
 2019  5030  4050
 2020  5040  4010
```

How would I be able to find which Year had the highest total of Boys + Girls (using R)?

Nothing I have seen after searching online shows me the code that will show the year that had the highest total, as well as the total number.

Comment: e.g. `df$Year[which.max(df$Boys + df$Girls)]`

Answer (score 1):

To show both the year and the highest total, use the following code:

```
df$Total <- df$Boys + df$Girls
df[which.max(df$Boys + df$Girls), c('Year', 'Total')]
```

The first line adds a column called `Total` with the total number of boys and girls, and the second line determines which row the largest total count is in and reports the value of the `Year` and the `Total` from that row.

Answer (score 0):

And the `tidyverse` way

```
## Construct data frame
df <- tibble(Year = 2018:2020, 
Boys=c(5000,5030,5040), 
Girls=c(4000,4050,4010))

df %>% 
mutate(Total = Boys + Girls) %>% # Add totals to the data frame
filter(Total == max(Total))   # Extract row with highest total
```